# StringField validation in Flask

Tags: python, string, validation, flask-wtforms

I am struggling with validation of the StringField in the below code. 
Email Validation and Date validation function correctly. But when I enter the string out of len range for surname/firstname there are no errors thrown.
All the import are correct.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eN0mo.png)Could you help me with that please?

class EmailForm(FlaskForm):

```
email = EmailField('Email', [validators.Email()])
postcode = StringField('Postcode')
surname = StringField('Surname', [validators.Length(3,45)])
firstname = StringField('First Name', [validators.Email(3,45)])
dateofbirth = DateField("Date Of Birth", default=date.today(), format='%d/%m/%Y')    
submit = SubmitField('GO')
```

Comment: Validating the StringField on Regex also doesn't work.

surname = StringField('Surname', [validators.required(), validators.regexp('^.{0,3}$')])

Comment: Also, if I add length validation to Email, it won't work either: email = EmailField('Email', [validators.Email(), validators.Length(min=6, max=120)])

Answer (score 0):

According to the [`wtforms`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/wtforms/) documentation, you need to specify 'min' and 'max' values on `validators.Length`.

In your case it should look something like this:

```
surname = StringField('Surname', [validators.Length(min=3, max=45)])
firstname = StringField('First Name', [validators.Length(min=3, max=45)])
```

Can you try this out and let me know if you're still having trouble with it?

EDIT: I just realised your `firstname` was `validators.Email` and not `validators.Length` too so I've edited my code above.

Comment: Yes! I have also tried that option, and validation won't work.

Comment: @Maria What version of Flask-WTF are you using? (from python: `import flask_wtf; print(flask_wtf.__version__)` or from pip: `pip freeze | grep Flask-WTF`) as I've tried `username = StringField('Username', validators=[Length(min=5, max=10)])` and `username = StringField('Username', [validators.Length(min=3, max=45)])` and both of trigger the validation in my code. Just to clarify, do you get an error message when you submit the form with the validation out of range?

Comment: Actually your first option "username = StringField('Username', validators=[Length(min=5, max=10)])" doesn't work for me 
There is an error when running project in cmd: 
name 'Length' is not defined

Comment: @Maria You'll need to import the Length from wtforms.validators - `from wtforms.validators import Length`